# Surface area of revolution about x-axis, Trig Function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

**Find the surface area of revolution when the line $y$ $=$ $cos((1/2)x)$ is rotated about the x-axis from $0\le x\le \pi$.**

So I got the integral to be:

$2\pi \int _0^{\pi }\:cos\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)}dx$

Using $u\:=\:sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)$ and $du=\frac{1}{2}cos\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)dx$, I got:

$2\pi \int _0^1\:\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}u^2}2du=2\pi \int _0^1\:\sqrt{4+u^2}du$

The using the trig sub of $u\:=\:2tan\theta $ I got:

$8\pi \int _0^1\:sec^3\theta$

Which became:

$4\pi \left(ln\left|tan\theta +sec\theta \right|+sec\theta tan\theta \right)$ for $0\le x\le \pi$

However, after this I got stuck. I am not even sure if the last couple of steps I have done above are correct. I am also a little confused because of the amount of substitutions. I am not sure how to plug in the appropriate values again.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

$u=2 \tan \theta$,

when $u=0, \theta = 0$.

when $u = 1$, $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac12$

You just have to substitute these corresponding values to evaluate the value.